# What role does the preposition “with” play in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-roles

What role does the preposition “with” play in this grammatical sentence?

1. Cheating is the way of man. We deny that all wars are based on deception.
   It can certainly be a big part of it.  However, **with bombs** and bullets flying and people dying;  it becomes a great reality.
2. The fighting in the disputed town of Lascaanod in the Sool region has entered its fifth week, **with heavy fighting** taking place on the outskirts of the town on March 6, according to the local authorities and quoted by the media. The international community continued to call for a peaceful solution to the war.

Comment: "In the situation that (X is happening_..."

Comment: What's with the semicolon in example 1?

Answer (score 1):

In both examples, *with* heads a preposition phrase that acts as adjunct (modifier or 'adverbial' if you prefer) in clause structure.

In the first example the adjunct is understood as one of reason, and in the second as a depictive or result.

> However, **with** bombs and bullets flying and people dying; it
> becomes a great reality.
>
> However, **because there are** bombs and bullets flying and people
> dying; it becomes a great reality.
>
> The fighting in the disputed town of Lascaanod in the Sool region has
> entered its fifth week, **with** heavy fighting taking place on the
> outskirts of the town on March 6, according to the local authorities
> and quoted by the media.
>
> The fighting in the disputed town of Lascaanod in the Sool region has
> entered its fifth week, **and there was** heavy fighting taking place
> on the outskirts of the town on March 6, according to the local
> authorities and quoted by the media.

Adjuncts with the form of *with + -ing clause* are mostly understood as reason or result, or as depictives which have an illustrative rather than a cause & effect relationship with the situation expressed in the matrix clause.

Comment: This lesson is very useful thank you so much